# LDAPS php binding issue

Tags: php, ldap

So I'm trying to `make a connection to a LDAPS server we can call SERVER2, but to me this should work, since I've tested it on another server called SERVER1, which uses LDAPS

```php
// using ldap bind
$ldaprdn  = 'xxxxx';     // ldap rdn or dn
$ldappass = 'xxxxx';  // associated password

// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldaps://xxxxx:3269")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {

    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
    }

}
```

But SERVER2 writes this warning:

`PHP Warning:  ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server`

So now I'm wondering if there is some kind of certificate problem with my LDAP(S) connection, but how do I check this?

SERVER1 is running XAMPP and I knew it also had LDAPS used in some of the pages. I then tried to use the exactly same code here and it works, then I thought that it might have been XAMPP that did something, so I tried to install XAMPP on SERVER2, but LDAPS still doesn't work on that, so there is something else.

Do some of you have any suggestions on where to look or some steps I could follow to debug this?

Comment: the error is quite clear, you need to verify connectivity to your server, using ping and telnet to target host

Comment: So I tried to connect to the ldaps with the windows tool LDP.EXE, and I can connect on both servers. So maybe its the IIS which has to be setup differently?